# Gsheets: place data in a column if it doesn't already appear in another column

Tags: workflow, matching

I'm trying to populate column A with all values that don't already appear in columns C or E.  Then column C will be populated with all values that don't already appear in column E.

[image: Screenshot of dummy data]

Answer (score 1):

Placing this here in case anyone lands at this question.  My solution was not eloquent but it got the job done.  Made a countifs column and carried each ID for every countifs=0 over to a new column which will show on the coverpage.